# Why is Q used in some words instead of K or C

Tags: orthography

For instance in words Iraq and Qashqai? Are there any historical reasons for that?

Comment: See also the related ["How do you spell Muammar Qaddafi?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13821/how-do-you-spell-muammar-qaddafi)

Comment: Qashqai being a Turkic tribe in Iran before it was a car.

Comment: English spelling is qweer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are a small number of words and names used in English that have Q but no U and do not correspond to a "kw" sound:

- Aqaba
- Haq
- Iraq
- Qasr
- qat
- Qatar
- Qi
- Qian
- Qiao
- Qing
- Qingdao
- souq
- Tariq

... among others

Most of these have a q because they are words or names that come from Arabic, which traditionally uses the letter Q to transcribe a sound that doesn't occur in English: the [voiceless uvular stop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_uvular_plosive), which sounds similar to but not quite like the sound of the letter "K", and is the sound usually used when saying these words in English.

A few of these—those starting with "QI", such as "Qi", "Qian", and "Qing"—come from Chinese, where Q is the letter used to transcribe a different sound—[the voiceless alveolo-palatal affricate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolo-palatal_affricate)—which sounds similar to but not quite like the sound of the "CH", and is the sound usually used when saying these words in English.

Comment: Heh. After living in China for a year, I kept pronouncing "Qatar" as /tʃæ tɑr/. Back to a /k'/ now though. Never did manage to pronounce the Chinese /t̠͡ɕ/ properly though. No matter how much I tried. I can barely hear the difference.

Comment: Also, I prefer to write "Qi" as "Chi", because that is much more commonly used. I don't see why we should write everything Chinese in simplified Pinyin.

Comment: @Vincent McNabb re:"Also, I prefer to write 'Qi' as 'Chi', because that is much more commonly used"—it's not in Scrabble ;-)

Comment: Heh. Well, that settles the argument then :-) It's also interesting to note that beer from Qingdao is called Tsingtao beer on the label, and that beer from Xinjiang is called Sinkiang.

Answer (score 8):

The place names that you mention are transliterations from Arabic, and the letter Q is traditionally used in transliterations of Arabic to represent a stop sound which doesn't exist in English.

Answer (score -1):

According to Shopify, the letter Q lends itself to fun branding and design treatments.

Here are a couple of recent product names that use a Q instead of a K:

Leqembi

Storq

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not apply to the specific examples that appear in the question. It is thus, at most, a supplement to the answer posted by nohat, rather than a stand-alone, complete answer.

Answer (score -2):

I remember from someplace that [older] Q words in English come from Latin words of Etruscan origin, and are always followed by a U. I guess that would probably apply to Romance languages too, but if so, then how come the French say "cinq" instead of "cinque"?

Comment: How would French people pronounce cinque, if it would be a French word?

Comment: I think cinq and coq are exceptions to the rule.

Comment: Possibly if *cinque* were a French word, the 'k' wouldn't go away before words like *cent*. That is, right now *cinq cent* (500) is pronounced without a 'k'. If if were spelled *cinque,* you would have to still pronounce the 'k' in *cinq cent*.